# Per instance widget preferences VS app preferences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

My app is currently using a subclass of PreferencesActivity for its preferences.
I am in the process of adding widgets, where each instance has its own preferences (I also offer multiple widget sizes, which means multiple subclasses of AppWidgetProvider).

The widgets and the app share most of their preferences, the widget actually supporting a few items less.

In the process of writing the widget configurator activity, I am realizing that I need to access a preferences layout which does not exist.
As I understand it, is not possible to access the PreferencesActivity layout in the configurator activity. Does this means that I must create a sepecific preferences layout for the configurator activity ? Do you have any tips on optimizing the overlap between app and widget preferences ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration activity does not to have to be a `PreferenceActivity`. Make it a normal `Activity` and use the `SharedPreferences.Editor` class to change the preferences the widget uses.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, but this is what I am doing alreaday.

Comment: No it wasn't. One way is to is move all configuration logic to the preference activity export the shared functionality as public static methods. Another is to split your `preferences.xml` into multiple files and try to make the configuration activity a `PreferenceActivity` as well, not sure how well this would work out though.

Comment: I am going the second way, using PreferenceActivity  for both the app and the widget. I create 2 preferences XML files. I load both XMLS in the app PreferenceActivity and only one in the widget activity. An "add widget" button can be added by loading a layout normally, with setContentView